# Add Facebook SDK Javascript code to Wordpress theme, to show that website ina Facebook Tab

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, sdk

This may be a dumb question but i'm not such a hacker (yet! hehehe)...

I have successfully developed a Facebook App to display my website in a Facebook tab inserting the following code right after the "body" tag to an HTML site:

```
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'MY_APP_ID_NUMBER',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.4'
        });

      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

You can see it here: https://www.facebook.com/jogojogomx/app_1096645967031976

You can see the original HTML site at jogojogo.mx

**BUT NOW, I want to do the same with a Wordpress themed website.** I have tried to put it in different .php files of the theme with no success...

See this link: https://www.facebook.com/Cochinita.YUKTK/app_1024054777627795

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!